# Not able to retrieve json data in Ajax call from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm able to convert my data into JSON format in php and while sending that data to Ajax call, I'm not able to get the details. In fact first the length of Json data shows 87, where it is actually 2.

My php code is

```
// credentials of MySql database.
$username = "root";
$password = "admin";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

$data = array();
//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("Angular",$dbhandle)
or die("Could not select Angular");
//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,password FROM User");

//fetch tha data from the database  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $id = $row{'id'};
    $name = $row{'name'};
    $password = $row{'password'};
    $data[] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'password' => $password);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

### Output it shows is

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Rafael",
        "password": "rafael"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Nadal",
        "password": "nadal"
    }
]
```

### My Ajax call is

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "ListUsers.php",
    success: function (dataCheck) {
        console.log(dataCheck.length);
        for(index in dataCheck) {
            /*
            console.log("Id:"+dataCheck[index].id);
                            console.log("Name:"+dataCheck[index].name);
                            console.log("Password:"+dataCheck[index].password);*/

        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error");
    }
 });
```

Please let me know if there is any thing wrong in my code

Comment: try JSON.parse function for converting data into array

Comment: use `dataType: 'json'` in ajax

Comment: Don't use `for (index in dataCheck)` to loop over an array. Use `for(index = 0; index < dataCheck.length; index++)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the dataType to 'JSON' and you are all set:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "ListUsers.php",
  success: function (dataCheck) {
    /* ... */
  },
  error: function () {
    alert("Error");
  },
  dataType: 'JSON'
});
```

Comment: Oh come on! How did I miss that? Thank you :)

Comment: Also: If you set the headers of your response correctly (Content-type: text/json), jquery will automagically parse the response as json.

Comment: ... and mark it as the answer please. Not for the points but for visibility when other people have the same question. This question gets asked quite often.

Answer (score 1):

The `dataCheck` inside success() is a string. You must convert it like this:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(dataCheck);
```

Now you can use it in you for loop like

```
data.forEach(function(item){

console.log(item.name)

});
```

Comment: Excellent. But, when I used to work with Java and it doesn't say anything like that?

Comment: And it again checks for the 3rd record even though it doesn't exist. I'm able to get the two records in console. The error is "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

**This should be your Ajax call:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "ListUsers.php",
    success: function (dataCheck) {
           var data = $.parseJSON(dataCheck);
           $(data).each(function(item){
                    console.log(item.name);
           });       
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error");
    }
 });
```